# SQL Bound variables error

Tags: mysql, bound-variable

I'm getting the error in my code. I'm sure this means there is something wrong with the column=:variable section of my code, but I've gone over it and can't see what's wrong.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in F:\...
```

Here is the code (long first line):

```
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE item_list SET quantity=:quantity, new_price=:newprice, image_link=:image_link, market_hash_name=:markethashname, last_update='1000-01-01 00:00:00', is_tradable='TEST', old_price=:oldprice WHERE item_name=:itemname AND (image_link IS NULL OR quantity IS NULL OR new_price IS NULL OR market_hash_name IS NULL OR last_update IS NULL OR is_tradable IS NULL OR old_price IS NULL)");
        $sql->bindParam(':quantity', $json2->quantity);
        $sql->bindParam(':newprice', $json2->lowest_price);
        $sql->bindParam('image_link', $image_link_full);
        $sql->bindParam(':markethashname', urlencode($mydata->market_hash_name));
        $sql->bindParam(':oldprice', $json2->lowest_price);
        $stmt->bindValue(':itemname', $mydata->market_name);
        $stmt->execute();
```

EDIT: image_link needed to be :image_link, still getting the same error

EDIT 2: Had a lot wrong, was using two names $sql and $stmt, using bindValue instead of bindParam

Comment: `image_link` should be `:image_link` in bind

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I just fixed it but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @Alex Can you see what else it should be?

Comment: are you sure about `$mydata->market_name` ? you use everywhere ` $json2->`

Comment: @Alex Yeah, I have that working in other sections of the code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a colon ':' before the 'image_link' in the bindParam statement.

Comment: Thanks for seeing that! I fixed it but I'm still getting the error, so there must be more.

Comment: Can you see what else it could be?

Comment: maybe bindValue vs. bindParam ??

Comment: Thanks, there was actually a fair bit wrong. Edited the question to explain it.